# Query model to get latest results first

Tags: laravel-5.4

How to query Model say **Post** to get latest post first. Descending order.

My question is that is there any in built method exists something like `latestFirst()` in Laravel 5.4 to query model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the latest post by ordering the posts by `created_at` column like this:

```
$latestPost = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
```

Comment: there is a method `latest()` available in Laravel framework.My quaetion is to know `latestFirst()` exists in Query builder or not?

Comment: Was there any in past? I mean Older version?

Comment: no, `latest()` and `oldest()` added on version 5.3. In the previous versions you could do it with the `orderBy()` function.

Comment: One of my older project uses this method on query builder object. How can I figure out where it is defined.

Comment: maybe this function is defined in Post model class. Or maybe the developer made a subclass from Model class and defined that function there

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `latest()`. For e.g:

```
$post = Post::latest()->first();
```

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries): *The latest and oldest methods allow you to easily order results by date. By default, result will be ordered by the created_at column. Or, you may pass the column name that you wish to sort by*